# file upload hasfile equivalent

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, file-upload

I'm looking for the equivalent of hasfile. I am not using an asp control like asp:fileUpload.

My html looks like this:

```
<input type="file" id="imagen" name="imagen" runat="server"/>
```

I have `enctype="multipart/form-data"` on my form.

My code behind looks like this:

```
nombreFichero = imagen.PostedFile.FileName
fileExtension = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(nombreFichero)

imagen.PostedFile.SaveAs(path & id_foto & fileExtension)
```

This works perfecty if I select a file. Has I explained on the title of the question I need the equivalent of using hasfile to check if I selected a file.

**This is what I've tried so far**

```
If imagen.PostedFile.ContentLength > 0 Then
     nombreFichero = imagen.PostedFile.FileName
     fileExtension = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(nombreFichero)
     imagen.PostedFile.SaveAs(path & id_foto & fileExtension)
End If
```

The code above doesn't work since the if statement catches an exception.
I just need to check if there is a file selected before doing

> PostedFile.SaveAs

Comment: Are you using MVC or WebForms ?

Comment: I am using WebForms.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".